# Generating large DataFrame in a distributed way in pyspark efficiently (without pyspark.sql.Row)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow, apache-arrow

The problem boils down to the following: I want to generate a DataFrame in pyspark using existing parallelized collection of inputs and a function which given one input can generate a relatively large batch of rows. In the example below I want to generate 10^12 rows dataframe using e.g. 1000 executors:

```
def generate_data(one_integer):
  import numpy as np
  from pyspark.sql import Row
  M = 10000000 # number of values to generate per seed, e.g. 10M
  np.random.seed(one_integer)
  np_array = np.random.random_sample(M) # generates an array of M random values
  row_type = Row("seed", "n", "x")
  return [row_type(one_integer, i, float(np_array[i])) for i in range(M)]

N = 100000 # number of seeds to try, e.g. 100K
list_of_integers = [i for i in range(N)]
list_of_integers_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list_of_integers)
row_rdd = list_of_integers_rdd.flatMap(list_of_integers_rdd)
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType, IntegerType
my_schema = StructType([
       StructField("seed", IntegerType()),
       StructField("n", IntegerType()),
       StructField("x", FloatType())])
df = spark.createDataFrame(row_rdd, schema=my_schema)
```

(I don't really want to study distribution of random numbers given seed - this is just an example I was able to come up with to illustrate the situation when large dataframe is not loaded from warehouse, but generated by the code)

The code above does pretty much exactly what I want. Problem is that it does it in a very inefficient way - at expense of creating a python Row object for each row, then converting the python Row objects into internal Spark columnar representation.

Is there a way I can convert batch of rows already in columnar representation (e.g. one or a few numpy arrays as above `np_array`) just by letting spark know that these are the columns of a batch of values?

E.g. I can write the code to generate python collection RDD where each element is an pyarrow.RecordBatch or a pandas.DataFrame, but I can't find a way to convert any of these into Spark DataFrame without creating an RDD of pyspark Row objects in the process.

There is at least a dozen of articles with examples how I can use pyarrow + pandas to convert a local (to driver) pandas dataframe to Spark dataframe efficiently, but that is not an option for me because I need data to be actually generated in a distributed way on executors rather than generating one pandas dataframe on driver and sending that to executors.

**UPD.**
I've found one way to avoid creation of Row objects - using RDD of python tuples. As expected it is still way too slow, but still a bit faster than using Row objects. Still, this is not really what I'm looking for (which is a really efficient way of passing columnar data to Spark from python).

Also measured time to do certain operations on a machine (crude way with quite a bit of variation in measured time, but still it representative in my opinion):
The dataset in question is 10M rows, 3 cols (one column is constant integer, other is integer range from 0 to 10M-1, third is floating point value generated using `np.random.random_sample`:

- Locally generate pandas dataframe (10M rows): ~440-450ms
- Locally generate python list of spark.sql.Row objects (10M rows): ~12-15s
- Locally generate python list of tuples representing rows (10M rows): ~3.4-3.5s

Generate Spark dataframe using just 1 executor and 1 initial seed value:

- using `spark.createDataFrame(row_rdd, schema=my_schema)`: ~70-80s
- using `spark.createDataFrame(tuple_rdd, schema=my_schema)`: ~40-45s
- (non-distributed creation) using `spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, schema=my_schema)`: ~0.4-0.5s (without pandas df generation itself which takes roughly same time) - with `spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled` set to true.

The example with local-to-driver pandas dataframe converted to Spark dataframe in ~1s for 10M rows gives me a reason to believe same should be possible with dataframes generated in executors. However fastest I can achieve now is ~40s for 10M rows using RDD of python tuples.

So the question still stays - is there a way to generate a large Spark dataframe in a distributed way efficiently in pyspark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the bottleneck is conversion from RDD -> Dataframes, and that the function at hand is fairly fast and that pandas DF conversions to spark DF via pyarrow are pretty fast. Here are two potential solutions:

1. Since it's easy to create pandas df's in parallel, instead of returning it from the executor, write the resulting df using `df.to_parquet`, ie:

```
def generate_data(seed):
    M = 10
    np.random.seed(seed)
    np_array = np.random.random_sample(M) # generates an array of M random values
    df = pd.DataFrame(np_array, columns=["x"])
    df["seed"] = seed
    df.reset_index().to_parquet(f"s3://bucket/part-{str(seed).zfill(5)}.parquet"
```

Spark reading in the resulting parquet files should be trivial afterwards. Then your bottleneck becomes IO limits, which should be faster than spark converting tuples/Row types.

2. If you're not allowed to save anything to file, `pandas_udf` and `GROUPED_MAP` might help you out, assuming your spark version is recent enough. It uses pyarrow as well to convert between spark DFs and pandas DFs so it should be faster than using tuples and allows you to create and return pandas DFs from your UDF in a distributed fashion.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

N = 10

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(i,) for i in range(N)], ["seed"]
)

def generate_data(seed):
    M = 10
    np.random.seed(seed)
    np_array = np.random.random_sample(M) # generates an array of M random values
    df = pd.DataFrame(np_array, columns=["x"])
    df["seed"] = seed
    return df.reset_index()

@pandas_udf("index long, x double, seed long", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def generate_data_udf(pdf):
    output = []
    for idx, row in pdf.iterrows():
        output.append(generate_data(row["seed"]))
    return pd.concat(output)


df.groupby("seed").apply(generate_data_udf).show()
```

The slower part will be the `groupby` which you might be able to speed up depending on how you batch the seed going into `generate_data_udf`, ie:

```
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def batch_seed(seed):
    return seed // 10

df.withColumn("batch_seed", batch_seed(col("seed"))). \
groupBy("batch_seed").apply(generate_data_udf).show()
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing something similar to option (1) but I can't use a distributed filesystem. I would be ok creating a DF from files written locally by executors, but I don't think there is any possibility to do that. Let me look into option (2).

Comment: Interesting. I actually looked at pandas UDFs before and didn't find a way to use them to generate custom number of rows (thought they only allowed either one-to-one transformations or aggregating multiple rows into one, but not explode-style generators or similar group-explode like here). Turned out I completely misunderstood the usage of `GROUPED_MAP` which actually allows generating custom amount of data. The solution with `GROUPED_MAP` is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. This is 4-20 times faster, than using RDD of tuples (depends a lot on how to measure). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution that is not using RDD or creating Rows, but only with dataframe operation:
(code is in scala, but doing the same in python should be simple)

```
val N = 100000

//for seed return array of index and random_value
def generate_data(i: Int): Array[(Int, Double)] = ???
val generate_data_udf = udf (generate_data _)

spark
  .range(N)
  .toDF("seed")
  .withColumn("arr", generate_data_udf($"seed"))
  .select(
    $"seed",
    explode($"arr") as "exp"
  )
  .select(
    $"seed",
    $"exp._1" as "n",
    $"exp._2" as "x"
  )
```

Comment: This is unfortunately much slower than even creating `Row` objects when done in python. The function to generate one row containing array-to-explode-later takes 3s to generate in my case, but that time is overshadowed by the time Spark needs to convert one row RDD like that to DF (~370 seconds in my case with schema specified and all that). I didn't measure time to do the explode, but expecting that to be negligibly small compared to other steps. So trying this in pyspark is approximately 5 times slower than using RDD of Row objects (and 10 times slower than using RDD of python tuples).

Answer (score -1):

Here's solution to your problem without using `Row` - only RDD based. I think it could be the most efficient way, since it uses `map` to calculate your function output and `flatMap` to combine those outputs - both those operations are performed on RDDs, so everything should be distributed.

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

def generate_data(one_integer):
  M = 2 # number of values to generate per seed, e.g. 10M
  np.random.seed(one_integer)
  np_array = np.random.random_sample(M) # generates an array of M random values
  return [(one_integer, i, float(np_array[i])) for i in range(M)]

N = 30 # number of seeds to try, e.g. 100K
list_of_integers = [i for i in range(N)]
list_of_integers_rdd = sc.parallelize(list_of_integers)
generated_data_rdd = list_of_integers_rdd.map(lambda x: generate_data(x))
solved_rdd = generated_data_rdd.flatMap(lambda list: list)

df = spark.createDataFrame(solved_rdd).toDF("seed", "n", "x")
df.show()
```

Comment: This method is already mentioned in my post in the evaluation part and it is still highly inefficient (the details are above inside my question).